# How to achieve MongoDB aggregation "switch" with java

Tags: java, mongodb

I need to find a way to achieve aggregation switch with Java.

I query MongoDB with aggregation switch successfully, but I don't know how to achieve it in Java with `BasicDBObject` class, not java-driver. Is there any way tell me the development doc or  the way to achieve it .

```js
db.collection.aggregate([{
    $project:{
        comment:1,
        sort: {
            $switch: {
                branches: [{case: {$eq: ["$checkStatus", 0]},then: 1},
                    {case: {$eq: ["$checkStatus", 1]},then: 3},
                    {case: {$eq: ["$checkStatus", 2]},then: 2}]
            }}}},
    {$sort: {sort:1}}
])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following is the Java equivalent code for the query:

```
List<BasicDBObject> aggregates = Arrays.asList(
                new BasicDBObject("$project", new BasicDBObject("comment", 1).append("sort", BasicDBObject.parse(
                        "{ $switch: { branches: [ { case: { $eq: ['$checkStatus', 0] }, then: 1 }, { case: { $eq: ['$checkStatus', 1] }, then: 3 }, { case: { $eq: ['$checkStatus', 2] }, then: 2 } ], 'default':-1 } }"))),
                new BasicDBObject("$sort", new BasicDBObject("sort", 1)));
```